# Curl PHP - strange internal server error

Tags: php, debian, libcurl

I have 2 servers. Server 1 has the engine/api. Server 2 has apache2 and my website.

From the website I try do a simple curl to the engine. If the curl lasts more than ~15sec I get internal server error. If I run this script from bash (not using a browser) I get status 200 and an answer. When I run this script from localhost to the engine it runs ok. But, when I want connect from my server via browser to engine - I get the internal server error after 15s.

I don't have any information in apache2 error_log. In php.ini I have the execution time = 120 and in apache I have 300 timeout. Do you have any idea what is wrong? (My server runs under debian lenny.) Sorry for my bad English.

```
$data = "Test text";
$_data['post'] = 'source_text='.urlencode($data);
$_data['url'] = ENGINE_PATH;
$_data['access'] = HTACCESS_LOGIN.':'.HTACCESS_PASSWORD;
$_curl = curl_init();

if(!empty($_data['post'])){
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data['post']);
}

if(substr($_data['url'],0,5) == 'https'){
    curl_setopt( $_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
}

curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_data['url']);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

if(!empty($_data['access'])){
    curl_setopt( $_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $_data['access']);
}

$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; pl-PL; rv:1.9.2.22) Gecko/20110905 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.22';

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}

curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

$data = curl_exec($_curl);
```

***EDIT***

I do simple script php -

```
 echo '1';
 sleep(16);
 echo '2';
```

But I get 500 error too.
I try this in apache2 and lighttpd.
Than I pretty sure - this is error configuration on system...

***EDIT***
Problem is solved. The problem was configuration of server pound. Thank you for help.

Comment: It might not even be a timeout issue .. do you have a proxy installed locally (eg fiddle)  or wireshark  ??? Configure curl then you would be able to trace the connection property ... you can post the full headers let me see

Comment: I use only firebug - track network. I get 500 always after 15sec.

Comment: Firebug can not capture request via CURL ... try downloading fiddle .. its free www.fiddler2.com/

Comment: Server with website -> Now I know that I'm inside of vserver.1) How I should configure Curl ?

Comment: Server with website -> Now I know that I'm inside of vserver.
1) How I should configure Curl ?
2) My server is debian - only console. 
3) I install wireshark but I get Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display.

Comment: wireshak would capture your traffic automatically but if you are using fiddle you need to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "localhost:8888"); to your curl script .... You are not to install it on your server .... but on your client machine and call it remotely ... don't experiment on your production servers directly

Comment: Ok problem is solved. A problem was server pound. I use tshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully check the logs. To display the error, add the following code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'script_error.log');
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: I try this but I don't get any error log. And yes I'm sure I have 120sec per max_execution_time

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `max_execution_time` is defined properly using `phpinfo()`.

Or try using `set_time_limit()`.

```
<?php
// run indefinitely
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Then it must be Apache. Why would you run extensive scripts like this over HTTP, anyway? Use the shell.